# how to call delete function declared in an angular controller when clicking button yes in a PopConfirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, popover

I'm working on a scala application with playframework, I want to use the popover confirm in a smart-table for the delete case, The question is how to execute the delete function which is declared in angular controller on the click on yes button of the popconfirm?

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger popconfirm" btn-delete><i class="hi hi-remove"></i>
                        </button>
```

there is my jquery-popconfirm file : http://pastebin.com/SinHkqCi

Also I'm using this directive to call my popconfirm :

```
app.directive('popconfirm', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'C',
  link: function(scope, element){
    element.popConfirm();
  }
};
});
```

Comment: Did you try using ng-click="yourDeleteFunction()" in your button?

Comment: yes, but it's delete without confirmation

Comment: Hey, did my answer work for you? Then it would be great to mark it as correct or give it an upvote :) Do you still have problems with the popover?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't work with your solution. I'm using only directive, but your solution sounds interesting. +1 vote

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap's popconfirm, I found this example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RDh7E/28/

Try something like this (from the mentioned example)

```
// (example jquery click event)
$('#important_action').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked, and valided this button !');
});

// Full featured example
$("[data-toggle='confirmation']").popConfirm({
    title: "Really ?",
    content: "I have warned you !",
    placement: "bottom"
});
```

html

```
<button class="btn btn-success popconfirm_full" data-toggle='confirmation' id="important_action">Full featured</button>
```

The important thing is, that the click event on the button calls the function that should be executed (probably also possible with angular's ng-click) and the popconfirm is handled via data-toggle='confirmation'. The example works but I haven't tried myself.